# Helm + ytt + argo

Tags: kubernetes, charts, kubernetes-helm, argo, ytt

I am a begginer developer. Please help to find my mistake
I have a helm chart with ytt .yml files. I going to deploy the chart in argo. There are many links for helm+argo/kubernetes, but poor with helm+ytt+argo/kubernetes.
My ytt files are in the templates.
During experimnets with steps getting in internet I got error related to sintax helm-ytt and resolved for example like  {{  to  {{ `{{ . But after that does not deployed to.
Please introduce some simple example for "helm+ytt+argo/kubernetes" or  take steps for "helm chart +ytt+argo/kubernetes". I need that wery wery mach

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

ArgoCD doesn't have a built-in ytt interpreter. You'd need to combine your deployment with kapp from carvel.dev.

I'd suggest to start simple, i.e. 1) ytt, then 2) ytt + kapp, afterwards 3) ytt + kapp + argocd, etc...

Answer (score 1):

While ArgoCD doesn't have a built-in ytt interpreter, it has at least two ways to integrate with other interpreters like ytt:

- a customizable plugins system,
- a sidecar system.

The customizable plugins system is relatively straightforward, and there is a [detailed ArgoCD + ytt integration example in the Carvel blog](https://carvel.dev/blog/argocd-carvel-plugin/). However, according to [ArgoCD documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operator-manual/config-management-plugins/), it is due to be deprecated eventually.

It is supposed to be replaced by the sidecar system, which is also detailed in the [same page of ArgoCD documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operator-manual/config-management-plugins/).

It's worth keeping in mind that the integration isn't as smooth as a native integration would be; for instance, passing values requires a bit of extra work (you'd have to use an annotated values file instead of `--data-values-file`, for instance).

(Thanks to @crenshaw-dev for pointing out that the plugins system will be eventually deprecated!)

Comment: Also note that configuring plugins via `argocd-cm` is deprecated - the preferred method is now with a sidecar. https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operator-manual/config-management-plugins/

Comment: Ohhh good catch, thanks! Do you think I should update my reply accordingly? (Unsure about what's the correct Stack Overflow etiquette there )

Comment: In my experience, SO etiquette is inscrutable. Might be nice to add a quick note, but tbh just go with what feels good.  :-D